# correct way to get HTML element Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently in my js code I'm using the following snippet to select an html element and do stuff.  Is there a better way in Angular.js to do this?

```
document.getElementById("someElement");
```

Comment: This seems to be a chicken and egg problem. Why do you want to select a html element in the first place? Angular is designed so DOM manipulation is a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.element('#someElement') //to select by id
angular.element('.someElement') //to select by class
```

Comment: This will only work if jQuery is also available on the page. From the [angular.element docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element): _"Note: Keep in mind that this function will not find elements by tag name / CSS selector"_

Answer (score 0):

Angular has angular.element which might be useful for this.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score -1):

AngularJS has a trimmed down version of jQuery ( jQLight ). That makes selection easier. Is it what it's best used for; selecting elements.

```
$('#someElement')
```

Comment: While angular does have a built-in subset of jQuery, it doesn't provide a definition for `$`. So using `$` will only work if jQuery is also available on the page.

Comment: Yes. As I said, angular _does_ provide a light-weight version of jQuery. But if jQuery itself is not also loaded on the page, using `$` [will not work](https://jsfiddle.net/y52ukh72/).